# Mouseover image change

Tags: image, mouseover, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to make a blur image change on mouseover. Something like camera zooming in and out with certain things get blurred when other is zoomed in. Best way to understand what I want is to see it here:
http://berger.co.rs/test/test.html

And I have only one problem. The mouseover image is always behind the active image. I need to have only active image and when mouseover is applied, then to change images. Also, I don't want active image to disappear in total, and then to load mouseover image. I need it like on example above, just not to have mouseover image shown behind all the time.

You can see whole code I have inside of the page source.

Can you please help me?

Comment: please reformulate... your question is very confusing

Comment: Please take a look at example site. There are 2 images one on top of the other. I just need image 1 (active image) to fade out and image 2 to fade in the place of image 1. Current situation is: Image 2 is behind image 1 and on mouseover image 1 fades out and image 2 just stays there. On mouseOut image 1 fadesIn again, but image 2 does not disappear at all. I want same effect, only image 2 to fade out on mouseout.

Comment: I have. Still confusing.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know enter posts comment. :)

Comment: Can you show some code you 're using ?

Comment: <script src="http://alturl.com/bcfhv"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document) 
.ready(function() 
{ 
$("div") 
.hover(function() 
{ 
$(this).children("span").fadeOut(); 
}, 
function() 
{ 
$(this).children("span").fadeIn(); 
}); 
}); 
</script>

Comment: <style type="text/css"> 
div{ 
position:relative; 
width:714px; 
height:420; 
overflow:hidden; 
} 
span{ 
position:absolute; 
top:0px; 
left:-0px; 
} 
</style>

Comment: <div> 
<img src="img/active.png" width="714" height="421"/> 
<span> 
<img src="img/mouseover.png" width="714" height="421"/> 
</span> 
</div>

Comment: that is complete page... I don't know what is the problem. I am graphic designer, not a programmer. I know basic html and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is just that you didn't provide Jquery for $() commands to work. "alturl.com/bcfhv" isn't correct.

Here, put this on file, it's working:

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
    div{ 
        position:relative; 
        width:714px; 
        height:420; 
        overflow:hidden; 
    } 
    span { 
        position:absolute; 
        top:0px; 
        left:-0px; 
    } 
</style>
<div> 
    <img src="http://berger.co.rs/test/img/mouseover.png" width="714" height="421"/> 
    <span> 
        <img src="http://berger.co.rs/test/img/active.png" width="714" height="421"/> 
    </span> 
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        alert('ok')
        $("div").hover(function() { 
            $("span").fadeIn(); 
        }, function() { 
            $("span").fadeOut(); 
        }); 
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v8wo54oe/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This example is still not working as I want. But thank you so much for your time.